# Where to put ”only" and "even"?

Tags: adverbs, word-order

1. Tom can't speak French.  He can't speak Spanish either.  He can [**only** speak English / speak **only** English].
2. Tom can speak French.  He can speak Spanish too.  He can [**even** speak Tagalog / speak **even** Tagalog].

Which one sounds right?

To me, "he can only speak English" sounds like "he doesn't do anything but speak English," while "he can speak only English" sounds like "he can't speak any languages other than English". Therefore, the latter sounds correct.

However, I have never heard anyone use "even" right in front of the object while I very often hear them put it before the verb.  So, "he can even speak Tagalog" sounds more familiar than "he can speak even Tagalog".

I often wonder where I should put "only" and "even".

Comment: Strictly speaking, adverbial ***only*** should go immediately before the word it modifies, so it's *He can speak only English* (***only*** modifies ***English***; he doesn't speak any *other* languages). But native speakers routinely introduce it earlier in many contexts, so *He can only speak English* is perfectly common. No-one is likely to misinterpret ***only*** as modifying ***speak***; it's unlikely the intended sense is that he can *speak* English, but not hear, read, or write it. But *Only he can speak English* is definitely different (it means no-one ***except him*** speaks English).

Answer (score 3):

With "only" both are possible, and mean the same. His only language is English.  The word *only* is a "creeper". It tends to move forward in a sentence, to positions that *logically* might mean something else.  The real meaning is understood pragmatically.  Of the two  "He can only speak English." is far more common.  "He only can speak English" would also be possible.

With "even" you should say "He can even speak Tagalog".  It also can creep forward. But whereas the adjective use of "only" works to mean (nothing else) the adjective "even" means "flat, without variation".  So "He speaks even Tagalog" would mean "He speaks a dialect of Tagalog that is flat and without variation."

Comment: A decent example of "only" as an adjective where it modifies nominals  (as opposed to NPs), is "My only concern is his lack of experience".

Comment: @James K, I understand, both are possible with "only". In addition to both alternatives, I thought of another alternative - a third one- regarding the location of only, but I am not sure if the meaning would still be the same. So I wonder if this would also be possible: "He can speak English only."

Comment: "He speaks English only" is not wrong, It would mean the same, but it isn't the normal position for the word "only".

Comment: That's a really excellent observation about ***only*** being a "creeper". It tends to creep ***forward*** in many utterances, presumably because it functions something like an "intensifier", and native speakers like to advertise the fact of emphasis as soon as possible (rather than have it appear nearer the end, almost as an "afterthought"). Obviously in OP's context it modifies ***English*** (no other languages), but we can shift it forward without risking being misunderstood (as no other actions apart from *speaking*).

Answer (score 1):

In the first set of examples, both of these are absolutely fine. In the first example, it would be a pretty unusual situation for someone not to be able to do anything but speak English, unless perhaps they are paralysed from the neck down. An English speaker will not interpret this in that way. It's clear from the context that **can only speak English** is referring to a lack of ability in any other languages, and not some disability where the person **can only speak**.

**He can only speak English** is a common way to say that someone is a monolingual English speaker.

In the second set of examples, **even** must come before **speak**, because **even Tagalog** would mean something entirely different, and to be honest it doesn't really make much sense in this context. It would mean something like speaking Tagalog in an even tone.

It may be helpful for you to check usage like this using the Google Ngram Viewer. Here's a [search for the first two constructions](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=can+only+speak+English%2C+can+speak+only+English&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), and [here for the second two](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=can+even+speak+English%2C+can+speak+even+English&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). As you can see, there are no examples of the last construction.  I had to use "English" in the last search, because I couldn't find any examples of either of these using the word "Tagalog".

Comment: I never thought of the possibility that ***only*** might modify ***can***. The idea that he can't do anything else apart from speak English just seems untenable (presumably he can eat, breathe, sleep, etc.). But there's at least *some* sense to having it modify ***speak*** - he can't read or write English, only speak it (although unless he's actually deaf, he can probably ***hear*** it too! :)